# Proof of approximation$~\sin\left(x^2\right)\approx x^2~~\text{where}~x~\text{is very small}$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations, approximation

I want to find out the fourth degree Maclaurin expansion of the following function.

$$f(x)=\sin\left(x^2\right)\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{0}}{\mathrm{d^{0}x}}f(x)=\sin\left(x^2\right)~\implies~f^{(0)}(0)=0\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{1}}{\mathrm{d^{1}x}}f(x)=2x\cos\left(x^2\right)~\implies~f^{(1)}(0)=0\tag{3}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d^{2}x}}f(x)=2\left(\cos\left(x^2\right)+x\left(-\sin\left(x^2\right)2 x\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

$$=2\left(\cos\left(x^2\right)-2x^2\sin\left(x^2\right)\right)~\implies~f^{(2)}(0)=2\tag{5}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{3}}{\mathrm{d^{3}x}}f(x)=2\left(-2x\sin\left(x^2\right)-2\left(2x\sin\left(x^2\right)+x^2\cdot 2 x\cos\left(x^2\right)\right)\right)\tag{6}$$

$$=2\left(-2x\sin\left(x^2\right)-4 x\sin\left(x^2\right)-4x^3\cos\left(x^2\right)\right)\tag{7}$$

$$=-4x\sin\left(x^2\right)-8x\sin\left(x^2\right)-8 x^3\cos\left(x^2\right)\tag{8}$$

$$=-12x\sin\left(x^2\right)-8x^3\cos\left(x^2\right)~\implies~f^{(3)}(0)=0\tag{9}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{4}}{\mathrm{d^{4}x}}f(x)=-12\left(\sin\left(x^2\right)+x\cdot 2x\cos\left(x^2\right)\right)-8\left(3x^2\cos\left(x^2\right)+x^3\cdot 2x\left(-\sin\left(x^2\right)\right)\right)\tag{10}$$

$$=\underbrace{16x^4\sin\left(x^2\right)-48 x^2\cos\left(x^2\right)-12\sin\left(x^2\right)}_{\text{Ommited detailed derivation}}~\implies~f^{(4)}(0)=0\tag{11}$$

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{f^{(i)}(0)\over i!}x^i\tag{12}$$

$$={f^{(0)}(0)\over 2!}x^2+\sum_{i=5}^{\infty}{f^{(i)}(0)\over i!}x^i\tag{13}$$

$$=x^2+\sum_{i=5}^{\infty}{f^{(i)}(0)\over i!}x^i\tag{14}$$

What I can't get is that as$~x~$is very small, then the following can be held.

$$\color{red}{f(x)\approx x^2}\tag{15}$$

I can guess$~5\leq\text{ith}~$derivative of$~f(x)~$with$~x=0~$is always$~0~$

But I don't have any clue to prove it, and moreover as it is held then symbol$~\approx~$is unnecesary.

Then why the approximation can be taken?

Comment: $\sin(z^2) = z^2 - (z^2)^3/3! + (z^2)^5/5! - \dots$, valid for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Let $k=x^2$. Therefore, $\sin(x^2)=\sin(k)\approx k = x^2$

Comment: @KingLogic In my opinion, the whole question, including your methodology, opens Pandora's box.  See my comments, following the answer of bubba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed (quite laboriously) that $\sin(x^2)$ is equal to $x^2$ plus some terms involving $x^5$ and higher powers. When $x$ is small, $x^5$ is much smaller than $x^2$ so you can just ignore the higher power terms and say that $\sin(x^2) \approx x^2$.

Comment: I am afraid that $~f^{(i)}(0)~$ may get larger which makes a numerator of $\frac{f^{(i)}(0)x^{i}}{i!}$ bigger which interrupt making value approximately$~0$.

Comment: Personally I may prefer the way of @KingLogic since it does not require us to think about the concern which I stated at above comment.

Comment: @electricalapprentice So do I.  However, then you open Pandora's box.  How do you know that $~\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1~?~$ Is it axiomatic, or something to be proven?  Before you try to use L'Hopital's rule, you must first determine how you know what the derivative of the sine and cosine functions are.  This may depend on what definitions are given for the sine and cosine functions.  So, for example, any attempt to involve the Taylor series in the discussion may be problematic.  ...see next comment

Comment: @electricalapprentice Further, before you trot out the geometric demonstration, that involves the unit circle, you have to question the relationship between the geometric (AKA Analytical Geometry or Trigonometry) definition of the sine and cosine functions, and the corresponding definitions in Real Analysis.

Comment: @user2661923 At least I've understood that talking about coefficients of Maclaurin expansion is opening Pandora's box for now.